# how to import data from production environment to Developer Pro Sandbox

Tags: data-loader, sandbox, import

I have a production environment of Salesforce.com with huge data (more than 15,000 records) .. I bought Developer Pro Sandbox and created it.
Now, I want to move my data to this Sandbox as it to do some tests on it.
I exported All records of each object from production salesforce using Data Loader application. But when I import these files to Sandbox the IDs changed and the relations (lookups fields) got errors.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ids will change because you are creating new records in the developer sandbox. I have found the easiest thing to do is to:

1. Create a productionId ExternalId field in each of the parent objects.
2. Import new parents and match original Id to productionId field
3. Upset children records and relate them to parent with original parentId matched to productionId field.

Comment: That's what I was going to say. Upsert can save countless hours of effort, and you get the side effect of knowing what record in production is related to in the Dev org. The only downside is that objects that don't support custom fields (e.g. AccountShare) may still need to be transformed manually, if you're getting that granular.

Comment: I created productionId field into Account object, and Imported (insert) accounts using Data loader with mapping productionId to ID, now after I tried to upsert contacts (Dataloader not show productionId into list of matching key on contact) . what is the problem with my scenario ?

Comment: @user3003810 did you make it an external Id field?

Comment: yes I did @JennyB

Comment: @user3003810 I use jitterbit but here are instructions for dataloader https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000002783&language=en_US not sure if you need to refresh the objects or not in dataloader after creating a new field like you do in jitterbit

Comment: productionId appears when I choose to upsert accounts not contacts

Comment: @user3003810 did you see it in step 2b as described in that help doc? In Step 2b: Choose your related objects select the External Id field for the Object A dropdown to use the External ID field for matching related Object A records upon importing Object B records.